# How do I group these results?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have this query to calculate the Idle Time of a vehicle.

The Business Rule for Idle Time is - `Ignition = 1 AND Speed = 0`

So I have came up with the following Query.

```
DECLARE 
      @startDate DATETIME = N'2018-09-08',
      @endDate DATETIME = N'2018-09-10 23:59:59.997';

Select
  iAssetId,
  fSpeedKPH,
  dtUtcDateTime,
  eIgnition,
  IdleSeconds = (CASE WHEN eIgnition = 1 AND fSpeedKPH = 0 THEN DateDiffSeconds ELSE 0 END)

FROM (

    Select
        iAssetId,
        fSpeedKPH,
        dtUTCDateTime,
        eIgnition,
        DateDiffSeconds = DATEDIFF(SECOND, dtUTCDateTime, LEAD(dtUTCDateTime, 1)
            OVER (PARTITION BY iAssetID ORDER BY dtUTCDateTime))    
    FROM VehicleMonitoringLog

    WHERE 
        dtUTCDateTime BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
        AND iAssetId = 2
) A

ORDER BY 
    iAssetId, dtUTCDateTime
```

**SQL FIDDLE - [Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f8469/2)**

Now I need to GROUP the Idle Times into Single Times. So the result set should look like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
iAssetId   |  Start Idle Time  | End Idle Time | Idle Duration (Seconds)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

How do I achieve this?

**EDIT**
Expected Result

```
iAssetId  | Start Idle Time      | End Idle Time        | Idle Duration (seconds) 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
2         | 08-Sep-2018 00:04:51 | 08-Sep-2018 00:36:51 |  1986
2         | 08-Sep-2018 00:58:28 | 08-Sep-2018 03:50:29 |  10432
```

Comment: Can you provide expected results for this? Do you want the min/max date and sum of idle times?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik I've tried to explain the result in the image - I need to group all idle times to get total idle. Once the vehicle starts moving the vehicle is stopped being idle

Comment: so in the image above this is one Idle Event - i.e. started at 00:04:51 and ending at 00:36:51 - then the difference between the two times is the total time the vehicle is idle

Comment: Yep, great, you have a clear idea what you want. Can you edit your question to show what your expected results are?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik I'll try that

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik done

Answer (score 2):

I *think* this gives you what you want.

My solution uses several common table expression and a variety of Window functions.

There are commented out selects at the bottom of each common table expression that you can use to check individual results along the way.

My first step was to identify the start and end idle times.  I used `LAG` to check for the previous value of `fSpeedKPH` and `eIgnition` ordered by `dtUtcDateTime`.  If the current values equal the previous values, no change occurred, else a change occurred.  A new column called IsChanged is added to the results.

```
 ;WITH _BaseData
AS (
    SELECT iAssetId
        ,fSpeedKPH
        ,dtUtcDateTime
        ,eIgnition
        ,IdleSeconds = (
            CASE 
                WHEN eIgnition = 1
                    AND fSpeedKPH = 0
                    THEN DateDiffSeconds
                ELSE 0
                END
            )
    FROM VehicleMonitoringLog
    )
--select * from _BaseData
    ,_BaseDataAndIsChanged  --cte to add IsChanged column to results
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,CASE 
            WHEN (
                    lag(fSpeedKPH, 1, '') OVER (
                        ORDER BY dtUtcDateTime
                        )
                    ) = fSpeedKPH
                AND (
                    lag(eIgnition, 1, '') OVER (
                        ORDER BY dtUtcDateTime
                        )
                    ) = eIgnition
                THEN 0
            ELSE 1
            END ischange
    FROM _BaseData
    )
    select * from _BaseDataAndIsChanged
```

---

My next step was to identify a grouping that I could use later to sum the `IdleSeconds` for each group.

```
;WITH _BaseData
AS (
    SELECT iAssetId
        ,fSpeedKPH
        ,dtUtcDateTime
        ,eIgnition
        ,IdleSeconds = (
            CASE 
                WHEN eIgnition = 1
                    AND fSpeedKPH = 0
                    THEN DateDiffSeconds
                ELSE 0
                END
            )
    FROM VehicleMonitoringLog
    )
--select * from _BaseData
    ,_BaseDataAndIsChanged  --cte to add IsChanged column to results
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,CASE 
            WHEN (
                    lag(fSpeedKPH, 1, '') OVER (
                        ORDER BY dtUtcDateTime
                        )
                    ) = fSpeedKPH
                AND (
                    lag(eIgnition, 1, '') OVER (
                        ORDER BY dtUtcDateTime
                        )
                    ) = eIgnition
                THEN 0
            ELSE 1
            END ischange
    FROM _BaseData
    )
--  select * from _BaseDataAndIsChanged
    ,_BaseDataAndGroups     --cte to add groupno column to results 
AS (
    SELECT t.*
        ,(
            SELECT sum(ischange)
            FROM _BaseDataAndIsChanged
            WHERE dtUTCDateTime <= t.dtUTCDateTime
            ) groupno
    FROM _BaseDataAndIsChanged t
    )
select * from _BaseDataAndGroups
```

---

The last step is to sum `IdleSeconds` by groups and find the `IdleStartTime` and `IdleEndTime` This is also the final query.

```
;WITH _BaseData
AS (
    SELECT iAssetId
        ,fSpeedKPH
        ,dtUtcDateTime
        ,eIgnition
        ,IdleSeconds = (
            CASE 
                WHEN eIgnition = 1
                    AND fSpeedKPH = 0
                    THEN DateDiffSeconds
                ELSE 0
                END
            )
    FROM VehicleMonitoringLog
    )
    --select * from _BaseData
    ,_BaseDataAndIsChanged --cte to add IsChanged column to results
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,CASE 
            WHEN (
                    lag(fSpeedKPH, 1, '') OVER (
                        ORDER BY dtUtcDateTime
                        )
                    ) = fSpeedKPH
                AND (
                    lag(eIgnition, 1, '') OVER (
                        ORDER BY dtUtcDateTime
                        )
                    ) = eIgnition
                THEN 0
            ELSE 1
            END ischange
    FROM _BaseData
    )
    --  select * from _BaseDataAndIsChanged
    ,_BaseDataAndGroups --cte to add groupno column to results 
AS (
    SELECT t.*
        ,(
            SELECT sum(ischange)
            FROM _BaseDataAndIsChanged
            WHERE dtUTCDateTime <= t.dtUTCDateTime
            ) groupno
    FROM _BaseDataAndIsChanged t
    )
    --select * from _BaseDataAndGroups
    ,BaseDataAndSums --cte to add SumIdleSeconds to results
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,sum(IdleSeconds) OVER (PARTITION BY groupno) AS IdleDurationSeconds
        ,FIRST_VALUE(dtUtcDateTime) OVER (
            PARTITION BY groupno ORDER BY dtUtcDateTime
            ) AS StartIdleTime
        ,LAST_VALUE(dtUtcDateTime) OVER (
            PARTITION BY groupno ORDER BY dtUtcDateTime RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                    AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
            ) AS EndIdleTime
    FROM _BaseDataAndGroups
    )
SELECT iAssetId
    ,StartIdleTime
    ,EndIdleTime
    ,IdleDurationSeconds
FROM BaseDataAndSums
WHERE ischange = 1
    AND IdleDurationSeconds > 0
```

---

```
| iAssetId | StartIdleTime           | EndIdleTime             | IdleDurationSeconds |
|----------|-------------------------|-------------------------|---------------------|
| 2        | 2018-09-08 00:04:51.000 | 2018-09-08 00:36:51.000 | 1986                |
| 2        | 2018-09-08 00:58:28.000 | 2018-09-08 03:50:29.000 | 10432               |
```

Comment: I like the group number you added to the Idle Groups - Will have a go at this

Comment: Question updated with expected results -- I think you can modify your query to get there easily.

Comment: @DawoodAwan - I see where you updated your question with your expected results.  I've updated my example.  Let me know if I have misunderstood your requirements.

Comment: @ScottHodgin this query is okay if i run it for records for 1 day - but when I run it for 1 week it keeps on running for 3 mins. Also because there are more than 1 assets data in the table I added the Partition By AssetId in the second CTE window function

Comment: @DawoodAwan - getting the correct results was the first step - now, you may have to investigate indexing strategies for window functions- there are numerous posts in the internet about indexing for window function - I’ve probably offered all I can for this question :)

Answer (score 0):

After lots of trying I came up with the following solution.

Which doesn't require me to create any New Indexes and Performance is good on larger sets.

```
Select
    AssetId,
    IdleStartTime = MIN(IdleStart),
    EndIdleTime = MAX(IdleEnd),
    -- idle duration is difference between Idle Start and Idle End Time
    IdleDurationSeconds = DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(IdleStart), MAX(IdleEnd))
FROM 
(
    Select
         IdleStart = idleStart.dtUTCDateTime
        ,AssetId = idleStart.iAssetId
        ,IdleStartSpeed = idleStart.fSpeedKPH

        ,IdleEnd = idleEnd.dtUTCDateTime
        ,IdleEndSpeed = idleEnd.fSpeedKPH

    FROM VehicleMonitoringLog idleStart

        -- GET the next location log with Speed > 0 and IGN == ON (vehicle start moving - no longer IDLE)
        CROSS APPLY (
            Select TOP (1)
                dtUTCDateTime, iAssetId, fSpeedKPH
            FROM VehicleMonitoringLog
            WHERE
                dtUTCDateTime > idleStart.dtUTCDateTime
                AND eIgnition = 1
                AND fSpeedKPH > 0
                AND iAssetId = idleStart.iAssetId
            ORDER BY dtUTCDateTime
        ) idleEnd

    -- idle start is when IGN is ON and Speed = 0
    WHERE 
         idleStart.eIgnition = 1 AND idleStart.fSpeedKPH = 0
) A

GROUP BY 
    AssetId, IdleEnd
ORDER BY AssetId, IdleEnd
```

It is also generates the correct result

```
| AssetId |        IdleStartTime |          EndIdleTime | IdleDurationSeconds |
|---------|----------------------|----------------------|---------------------|
|       2 | 2018-09-08 00:04:51  | 2018-09-08 00:37:57  |                1986 |
|       2 | 2018-09-08 00:58:28  | 2018-09-08 03:52:20  |               10432 |
```